# How to change image properties dialog in wxpython RichTextCtrl

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

When I insert an image into a RichTextCtrl in wxPython and right click on it I get a menu which has a Picture button and opens a Picture properties dialog.

Is there a way I could substitute that dialog for a custom dialog that I make and get the image information into it?

Ideally I want to get the image data or even better the filename of the image.
But looking at the xml that RichTextCtrl produces I do not think recovering the filename is possible. But if I could get the data I might be able to find the image.

The on_right_click method below is able to completely consume the event and prevent the menu from showing if you remove the Skip() but I was not able to find out how to get any information on what has been clicked on.

Here is an example code in python3 wxPython 4.1.0 that lets you insert a image and click on it and save the document in xml:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt


class RichTextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.make_menu_bar()
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, style=wx.VSCROLL | wx.HSCROLL | wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.sizer.Add(self.rtc, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        rt.RichTextBuffer.AddHandler(rt.RichTextXMLHandler(name="XML", ext="xml", type=99))
        self.Bind(rt.EVT_RICHTEXT_RIGHT_CLICK, self.on_right_click)

    def on_right_click(self, evt):
        # This catches right clicks
        evt.Skip()

    def on_file_save_as(self, evt):
        wildcard, types = rt.RichTextBuffer.GetExtWildcard(save=True)

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a filename",
                            wildcard=wildcard,
                            style=wx.FD_SAVE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            if path:
                file_type = types[dlg.GetFilterIndex()]
                ext = rt.RichTextBuffer.FindHandlerByType(file_type).GetExtension()
                if not path.endswith(ext):
                    path += '.' + ext
                self.rtc.SaveFile(path, file_type)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def on_insert_image(self, evt):
        # wx.Image('image.png'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        self.rtc.WriteImage(wx.Image(200, 200))

    def on_file_exit(self, evt):
        self.Close(True)

    def forward_event(self, evt):
        self.rtc.ProcessEvent(evt)

    def make_menu_bar(self):
        def do_bind(item, handler, update_ui=None):
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler, item)
            if update_ui is not None:
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, update_ui, item)

        file_menu = wx.Menu()
        do_bind(file_menu.Append(-1, "&Save\tCtrl+S", "Save a file"),
                self.on_file_save_as)
        do_bind(file_menu.Append(-1, "E&xit\tCtrl+Q", "Quit this program"),
                self.on_file_exit)

        edit_menu = wx.Menu()
        do_bind(edit_menu.Append(-1, 'Insert image\tCtrl+i'), self.on_insert_image)

        mb = wx.MenuBar()
        mb.Append(file_menu, "&File")
        mb.Append(edit_menu, "&Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(mb)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    """
    Main class for running the gui
    """

    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.frame = None

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = RichTextFrame(None, -1, "RichTextCtrl", size=(900, 500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        print('_Done_')
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without making your own widget. By the way, the event you are catching (EVT_RICHTEXT_RIGHT_CLICK) refers to the event of the widget not its content (image or whatever). They are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to get this to work with the WriteImage. But I did workaround it by using a custom subclass of RichTextFieldTypeStandard that can hold an image which overrides methods: CanEditProperties, GetPropertiesMenuLabel and EditProperties.
By inserting a field like this in the text, the EditProperties method can access the field's name which can be a path to the image on disk.